# How to store a variable's value in a list and not have it changed when that variable is altered?

Tags: c#, arrays, list, variables, stored-procedures

I'm trying to have a list that stores the current position of a character inside it, as well as previous positions. Before this code begins, the characters moves one column/row and has it's current_position is updated in another method. If the list of positions becomes bigger than (move_counter+1), the first item is removed.

However, when I run this part of the code, the current_position which was previously stored in the list is also changed.

So let's say we begin with a list: {[6,7],[7,7]} and current position [7,7]. (these are the default initial values I feed into it, [6,7] being a random starting position and [7,7] the initial current_position)

After one move to position [8,7], the list immediately changes to {[6,7],[8,7]}. Then when running the code, it becomes {[8,7],[8,7]}, when it should've been {[7,7],[8,7]}, storing the last known current_position and the current current_position.

```css
list_size= known_cells.Count;
known_cells.Add(current_position);
if (list_size > (move_counter + 1))
      {
      dataGridView1.Rows[known_cells[0][0]].Cells[known_cells[0][1]].Style.BackColor = Color.LightGray;
      known_cells.RemoveAt(0);
     
      }
```

Hope this wasn't too chaotic an explanation. Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: Can you please explain again what is the list doing?

Comment: Yeah, sure! The list stores the past 'relevant' positions of the character so that the tiles he was in are colored Brown. If he's far enough away (move_counter), the tiles should gradually go back to their original color of LightGray, as seen in the code!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect your `current_position` is some reference type. When you then do `known_cells.Add(current_position)`, you are not adding the current *value*, but a **reference** to that value.

When you later change the properties, those changes are also seen though that reference in the list.

Solution: change to an "immutable" class. So instead of

```
class ThePosition
{
   public int Coord1 {get; set;}
   public int Coord2 {get; set;}

   public ThePosition() {} 
   // default constructor that will also be added by the compiler
}
```

make sure that the properties cannot be changed:

```
class ThePosition
{
   public int Coord1 {get; private set;}
   public int Coord2 {get; private set;}

   public ThePosition(int c1, int c2) 
   {
      Coord1 = c1; Coord2 = c2;
   } 
   // no default constructor!
}
```

So you will need to create a new instance to store a different position: `current_position = new ThePosition(7,8);`.

Comment: Wow, this is exactly what I had thought, but had no idea how to do! I was thinking of storing the 'absolute' value of the current_position variable, not a reference of is, as you mentioned. I'll try it out, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The list is {[8,7],[8,7]} because you have updated the current position to [8,7] before this piece of code.
To break it down,

The list becomes {[6,7],[8,7]}.

Then, known_cells.Add(current_position); will add the current position [8,7]. So the list becomes {[6,7],[8,7],[8,7]}.

Now the 'if' condition will remove the first element [6,7].

Hence you are left with the list {[8,7],[8,7]}

I suggest you add [8,7] rather than replacing [7,7] with [8,7] and then remove the first element. 
Hope this wasn't too chaotic an explanation :)

Comment: Thanks for your answer! That is true, however the 'known_cells' is not present in any other part of the code! The problem is whenever any change is made to the variable current_position, all the values previously stored in the list are immediately changed!

Answer (score -1):

```
class Coord()
{
   int x = 0;
   int y = 0;
   public Coord(int x,int y)
   {
     x=x;
     y=y;
   }
}

class Game()
{
    List<Coord> coords = new List<Coord>();


    public void AddCoord(Coord c)
    {
       coords.Add(c);
       if(coords.Count>maxAmount)
       {
          coords.RemoveAt(0);
       }
    }
}
```

Comment: What exactly do you mean by this dump of code that seems unrelated to the OP?

Comment: I show how it must be done. If he would provide more code without those "blank" spots, I would write more issue related code.